# Python how to call a method from another module inside a class method

Tags: python-3.x, flask-sqlalchemy

So I have two files such that

```
# functions.py
#I have a suspicion this 2 way import might be an issue
from models import *

def foo():
    return 'bar'

def some_other_unrelated_foo():
    users = User.query.all()
    return users
```

and

```
#models
from functions import *

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(), unique=True)

    def name_and_foo(self):
        return self.username + foo()
```

But if I try:

```
print(user_a.name_and_foo())
```

I get the error:

```
NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
```

If instead i have one file:

```
#models

def foo():
    return 'bar'

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(), unique=True)

    def name_and_foo(self):
        return self.username + foo()
```

I get the correct:

```
print(user_a.name_and_foo())
result: "user_abar"
```

What is the correct way to have the functions from functions.py visible to the class methods in models.py?

Comment: What happens if you try `from functions import foo`? Also, how is this being run? From command line in the working directory?

Comment: Just a heads up, wildcard imports like this `from models import *` hide potential errors that can help with debugging.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the function first.

```
#models
from functions import *

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    foo = foo()
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(), unique=True)

    def name_and_foo(self):
        return self.username + foo()
```

Make sure your files are in the same place though, that can also be the problem at time

Comment: You don't. OP mentioned that it works when the function is in the same file. Additionally, the only way this could ever work is if `foo` would return a function or callable. This line `foo = foo()` sets `foo` to `'bar'` and then this line `return self.username + foo()` would raise both a `NameError` and an error for trying to call a string.

Answer (score 0):

OK I solved this shortly after posting, I moved the imports to the bottom of both files for each other and this seems to solve it. I am not 100% clear on why this works tho.